# Eclipse egit pull says up to date even though there are changes in remote repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have some code changes in my remote repository. But If I try to pull it says upto date nothing to commit.

[image]

I also tried with command prompt but it throws NullReferenceException error

[image]

I am new to git. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: A _fetch_ only fetches the changes to your local repository (into the remote tracking branch), not into your local branch. You have to do a _pull_ to make the changes from remote visible in the files you edit.

Comment: However, this doesn't explain the failing `fetch`, and in this case `pull` is guaranteed to fail as well.

Comment: @howlger git pull says  updto  date . Updated the screenshot

Comment: @NareshShetty The changes might be on different branches.

Comment: @IamGrooot did you find the solution?